# Error? Ext4-fs (sda6): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities

Tags: ext4

In recent weeks, when the attempt system boot Ubuntu, the following information appears on the screen with black background:

Ext4-fs (sda6): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities.
Ext4-fs (sda6): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities.

Friends, can you tell me how to interpret these messages, and what could do about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you marked the partition as ext3 in /etc/fstab, when in fact it is ext4 ( or you have since converted it with `tune2fs` ).  Change the ext3 designation to ext4 in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found it easier to reinstall the operating system and putting on ubuntu Mate 15.10. Apparently, the new kernel updates were causing me the problem because since that I have not updated the problem didn't appear again.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this bright red message in my dmesg output and got curious although I am not experiencing any problems. I checked the hint from psusi's answer but `/etc/fstab` is set to ext4 on my system. After some more research I found [this post in the arch forum](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=10451#p52303) with an explanation that sounds resonable to me. The gist: The ext-fs driver supports multiple versions and checks which one works if none is specified at boot time. My kernel command line reads `root=/dev/xvda ro console=xvc0 console=hvc0` so it looks like auto-detection is required.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me recently after a package upgrade leaving me with a low resolution login screen that wouldn't work. (Ubuntu 16.04)

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get a terminal and login via this terminal.
- Run following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  sudo reboot
  ```

Hope this helps ...